# Kafka/Snowflake Connector: "snowflake.schema.name schema does not exist"

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I try to use the Snowflake Connector (snowflake-kafka-connector-2.0.0.jar
) in my Kafka (kafka_2.13-3.5.0). But when starting the connector, I get: "snowflake.schema.name schema does not exist". But I have set a schema name. I tried with PUBLIC, which is available in Snowflake, and also with a different schema that I have setup in Snowflake. I also created a probably correct table within Snowflake, but does not work with or without it.
I am trying with a user that has the ACCOUNTADMIN role and I gave all the rights to this role.

This is my SF_connect.properties:

```
name=KafkaConnector
connector.class=com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector
tasks.max=8
topics=tokenize-output
buffer.count.records=10000
buffer.flush.time=60
buffer.size.bytes=5000000
snowflake.url.name=<host>.snowflakecomputing.com:443
snowflake.user.name=KAFKA_CONNECTOR_WJ
snowflake.private.key=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MII...-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
snowflake.database.name=KAFKA_WJ_TEST
snowflake.schema.name=PUBLIC
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

These are my Snowflake schemas and the grants to the role ACCOUNTADMIN:

This is the stack trace:

```
[2023-08-17 09:53:03,270] INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:57)
[2023-08-17 09:53:03,496] INFO [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Establishing a JDBC connection with url:jdbc:snowflake://mya39555.snowflakecomputing.com:443 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1:46)
[2023-08-17 09:53:05,315] INFO [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] initialized the snowflake connection (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1:46)
[2023-08-17 09:53:06,722] INFO [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] database KAFKA_WJ_TEST exists (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1:46)
[2023-08-17 09:53:07,020] ERROR [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Validate Error msg:[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Exception: Failed to prepare SQL statement
Error Code: 2001
Detail: SQL Exception, reported by Snowflake JDBC
Message: SQL compilation error:
Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowExceptionSub(SnowflakeUtil.java:129)
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:70)
net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.pollForOutput(StmtUtil.java:456)
net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:366)
net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:464)
net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQueryInternal(SFStatement.java:192)
net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:129)
net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:742)
net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:652)
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.executeInternal(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:310)
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.execute(SnowflakePreparedStatementV1.java:458)
com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1.schemaExists(SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1.java:655)
com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector.validate(SnowflakeSinkConnector.java:270)
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:509)
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$2(AbstractHerder.java:390)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829), errorCode:2001 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector:94)
[2023-08-17 09:53:07,022] INFO AbstractConfig values:
 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:369)
[2023-08-17 09:53:07,037] ERROR Failed to create connector for /opt/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.5.0/config/SF_connect.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:74)
[2023-08-17 09:53:07,038] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:84)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
snowflake.schema.name schema does not exist
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:123)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:107)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.processExtraArgs(ConnectStandalone.java:81)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.startConnect(AbstractConnectCli.java:150)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.run(AbstractConnectCli.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:112)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
snowflake.schema.name schema does not exist
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.maybeAddConfigErrors(AbstractHerder.java:754)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:207)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.lambda$null$0(StandaloneHerder.java:193)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2023-08-17 09:53:07,039] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:67)
```

I searched Google but just do not find an answer to my problem. Does anyone know?
When starting the standalone connector with /opt/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.5.0/bin/connect-standalone.sh /opt/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.5.0/config/connect-standalone.properties /opt/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.5.0/config/SF_connect.properties
I expected my data to be written from my Kafka Topic to Snowflake.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: You mentioned that all required permissions are granted to ACCOUNTADMIN, in your I see you are not setting the name of the role, so it connects with the default role assigned to the user, which can be different to account admin. Could you please either adding to you config: ```snowflake.role.name=ACCOUNTADMIN``` or in Snowflake: ```alter user <kafka_username> set default_role = 'ACCOUNTADMIN';```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint @OneCricketeer. Unfortunately it does not work. Tried both of your suggestions. Still same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: That wasn't my comment

Comment: Any other idea @aek?